# Regex Grab files names based on a list of file extensions

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex which seems to work as far as identifying the strings in the provided list, but i need to grab everything from the identified string up to the beginning of the token NO MATTER WHAT CHARACTERS ARE IN IT.

```
^.*?\b(png|dll|exe|docx|pdf)\b.*$
```

I'm searching the following test string:

```
The filename is test.exe will I be able to find it
The file name is bob.png
the file name is my filename.pdf, we love pdfs
the file name is question.png
this is my word file.docx
this is my odd file[.]png
```

I want to find:

```
test.exe
bob.png
filename.pdf
question.png
file.docx
file[.]png
```

I just realized too.. that there may be an issue with "we love pdfs" with this approach too.. so any help for that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you asked for:**

Just look for an amount of non-space characters leading up to the extensions:

```
/^.*?\b(\S+(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))\b.*$/gm
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aJ3gV5/1

The above working in python, to illustrate the difference. Observe that there is only one match on the bottom line.

```
>>> s = """The filename is test.exe will I be able to find it
... The file name is bob.png
... the file name is my filename.pdf, we love pdfs
... the file name is question.png
... this is my word file.docx
... this is my odd file[.]png file2[.]png"""
>>> re.findall(r"(?m)^.*?\b(\S+(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))\b.*$", s)
['test.exe', 'bob.png', 'filename.pdf', 'question.png', 'file.docx', 'file[.]png']
```

Just to illustrate the regex below on the same input:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\S+(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))", s)
['test.exe', 'bob.png', 'filename.pdf', 'question.png', 'file.docx', 'file[.]png', 'file2[.]png']
```

**What I recommend:**

There is no point in matching complete lines, unless you only want the first match of each line. You can find more results with this one:

```
/(\S+(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aJ3gV5/2

Since you stated in another comment you might use python, here's it working in python:

```
>>> s = """The filename is test.exe will I be able to find it
... The file name is bob.png
... the file name is my filename.pdf, we love pdfs
... the file name is question.png
... this is my word file.docx
... this is my odd file[.]png"""
>>> re.findall(r"(\S+(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))", s)
['test.exe', 'bob.png', 'filename.pdf', 'question.png', 'file.docx', 'file[.]png']
```

EDIT:

Forcing the match of a dot as well can be done by augmenting the start of the regex with:

```
\S+\.\S*
/(\S+\.\S*(?:png|dll|exe|docx|pdf))/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aJ3gV5/4

Comment: Is there a way to adjust it so that the list only matches if the match is on the last part of the string?  For instance.. the query works well, but in a scenario like "thisismypdfs" I get a match because it matches "pdf".  I may just say it needs to contain a . as well.. or both

Comment: So you want to match the dot? You've already shown that the dot can be wrapped by brackets, what else?

Comment: I agree the brackets are an issue..otherwise I'd just make the list .pdf|.docx etc..

Comment: There, made it as general as I could. Note that this matches some new stuff in the demo there. You can prevent that by replacing `*` with `?`, matching 0 or 1 non-space character after the dot.